# Converting multisurface geometries to multipolygon with GDAL/OGR

Tags: gdal, c#

While processing a multisurface geometry for storage in an older system using the C# bindings of GDAL/OGR, both `Ogr.ForceToMultiPolygon` and `ToLinearGeometry(0,null)` return a multipolygon with overlapping shells, where the objects that were once holes are now overlapping polygons in the same coordinate orientation.  What is the most accurate method of achieving a conversion from multisurface to multipolygon with GDAL/OGR without losing the relationship of the holes?

```
        using (var geom = sourceFeature.GetGeometryRef())
        {
            if (geom.GetGeometryType() == wkbGeometryType.wkbMultiSurface)
            {
                var linearStringGeom = geom.GetLinearGeometry(0, null);

                var multiPolygonGeom = Ogr.ForceToMultiPolygon(geom);
        
            }
        }
```

EDIT:

WKT as exported by GDAL/OGR:

`geom.ExportToWkt(out string geomAsWkt)`
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fx3ykrk4p8i32tk/MultiSurfaceWKT.txt?dl=0

WKT as exported by ESRI:

`for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("interestingfeature", ["SHAPE@WKT"]): print(row[0])`

https://www.dropbox.com/s/w2jwui76em3222r/ESRIWKT.txt?dl=0

Comment: How was this closed for being "Not suitable for this site"? It did have a clear problem statement from the very beginning and it is about a GDAL/OGR issue.

Comment: @bugmenot123 Post reopened after editing post to include pertinent code.

Comment: Could you include one such multisurface geometry for example as GML?

Comment: Calling `ExportToGML()` raises an exception of "Unsupported geometry type Multi Surface"

I've exported it to WKT and put it on dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fx3ykrk4p8i32tk/MultiSurfaceWKT.txt?dl=0

Comment: @Aaron one should not have to make up a code example of *surrounding* code if the question is about a specific kind of object and methods available by the API. That's just putting extra work onto the asker without any benefit.

Comment: I can see that PostGIS ST_CurveToLine creates the most eastern part of the multipolygon so that it has a small overlapping polygon. The source geometry is rather large. Would you mind to try to remove as much as possible from the original geometry and simplify what remains? It would make investigation more enjoyable. How do you know that the original geometry is valid?

Comment: We moved to GDAL/OGR from ESRI because of cost, and these polygons have been static for some time.  It does appear that GDAL/OGR finds this invalid due to nesting shells.  What's odd is that simplifying the geometry by removing all of the vertices except for the overlap now appears to make the process work.  
https://www.dropbox.com/s/v4hheu7d0z5twkb/multiPolygonSingleWithHole.txt?dl=0
I fear this could be a disassociation between GIS software, with the creator being in a different suite of software than what GDAL/OGR deems valid.  I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: I added the ESRI WKT of the same full shape into the question above.  That appears to be a simplified linear version that preserves the relationship of the hole to the polygon that contains it, whereas GDAL/OGR exports a multisurface with curves that create the hole at the same level as the polygon it should be contained in, thereby creating an overlapping shell.  Is there a setting that I'm missing?  Is there a way to bridge this gap between two GIS software suites?